# M-M mapping with EF Code First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two class with following structure

```
public class FeatureClaim : Entity<Guid>
    {

        public FeatureClaim()
        {
            ApplicationFeatures = new List<ApplicationFeature>();
        }

        public string ClaimType { get; set; }
        public string ClaimValue { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationFeature> ApplicationFeatures { get; protected set; }
    }





public class ApplicationFeature : Entity<Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationFeature()
        {
            FeatureClaims=new List<FeatureClaim>();
        }

        public string FeatureName { get; set; }
        public string FeatureCode { get; set; }
        public Guid ApplicationResourceId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<FeatureClaim> FeatureClaims { get; protected set; }
    }
```

This two class has M-M relationship, i configured this relationship through fluent api.
    The configuration looks like .

```
public class ApplicationFeatureEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationFeature>
    {

        public ApplicationFeatureEntityConfiguration()
        {
             HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x=>x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.ApplicationResourceId).IsRequired();
            Property(x => x.FeatureCode).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            Property(x => x.FeatureName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);

            HasMany(x => x.FeatureClaims).WithMany(z => z.ApplicationFeatures).Map(

              m =>
              {
                  m.MapLeftKey("ApplicationFeatureId");
                  m.MapRightKey("FeatureClaimId");
                  ToTable("ApplicationFeatureFeatureClaims");

              }
              );

            Property(x => x.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
        }
    }
    public class FeatureEnityClaimConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FeatureClaim>
    {
        public FeatureEnityClaimConfiguration()
        {
             HasKey(x => x.Id).Property(x=>x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();

            Property(x => x.ClaimType).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);
            Property(x => x.ClaimValue).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);

            HasMany(x => x.ApplicationFeatures).WithMany(z => z.FeatureClaims).Map(

                m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("ApplicationFeatureId");
                    m.MapRightKey("FeatureClaimId");
                    ToTable("ApplicationFeatureFeatureClaims");

                }
                );
        }
    }
```

But when i am migrating  i am getting the following error

***The entity types 'FeatureClaim' and 'ApplicationFeature' cannot share table 'ApplicationFeatureFeatureClaims' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.***

What is wrong with this configurations? How i can solve this issue by changing my configuration /class definition.please not i am not using Lazy loading. i should achieve this throw fluent api configuration

Comment: try defining the M to M in only one configuration class. This should be enough.

Comment: @tschmit007  tried but same result